# Include custom attributes using Spring Cloud Stream (StreamBridge)

Tags: google-cloud-pubsub, spring-cloud-stream

This document describes how to include custom attributes into PubSub messages.

https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/samples/pubsub-publish-custom-attributes

Is this possible using the newer Spring Cloud Stream functional APIs?

```
streamBridge.send("myEvent-out-0", event)
```

I am currently publishing as per above. The second param is just of type "Object", so no way to differentiate custom v regular attributes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can publish Spring `Message` and specify your attributes as headers

```
streamBridge.send("myEvent-out-0", MessageBuilder
    .withPayload(event).setHeader("fooKey", "fooValue").setHeader("barKey", "barValue").build());
```